# Display Custom messages in MiniProfiler

Tags: c#, .net, mvc-mini-profiler

I have added miniprofiler and am able to see the timings for all requests. Can I display trace messages (or any other custom information for that matter) using Miniprofiler. Please help on the possibility. I'm Using it in MVC3 .net C# website.

Answer (score 5):

You can profile subsections of code in your app by using the following syntax:

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Extremely Complex Stuff")) 
{
  var data = myClass.GetSomeDate();
  data.Process();
}
```

You can also add Custom Timings to be profiled (good for profiling specific types of interactions other than sql, for example: redis/caching integration) by using `CustomTiming`:

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.CustomTiming("Redis", "GetData")) 
{
  var data = CacheHelper.GetDataFromCache();
}
```

I would suggest cloning the repo and playing around with the [Sample.MVC app](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/Sample.Mvc) to see more of the things that can be done (it demos all of what I said, out of the box).

Answer (score 2):

Just a small improvement on Yaakov's answer,

If you include your cache key, such as

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.CustomTiming("Redis", key)) 
{
  var data = CacheHelper.GetDataFromCache();
}
```

Then your MP traces will be more useful as they will tell you which keys are being accessed, and you will be warned of any duplicates.